# Windows doesn't recognize Ubuntu DVD

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, multi-boot, easybcd

I want to dual boot my laptop, but Windows doesn't read the Ubuntu DVD.  It doesn't recognize it, nor a Linux Mint DVD.

Two days ago I installed Mint 13, then removed it because of installation errors, and changed some stuff using EasyBCD.  Now it doesn't read the Linux Mint DVD.  It doesn't recognize it.  I can insert any game DVD and it works, but the Linux Mint DVD and Ubuntu DVD doesn't work.  I think it's some BIOS error.

I can't access my BIOS.  I tried all the F function keys and none of them work.  How can I fix this?

**update**

i was finally able to boot ubuntu, but it freezes, after bootimg, it shows me the purple screen and then it shows me a black screen and it freezes

Comment: Is it Toshiba laptop?

Comment: @C2940680 hp pavillion g6

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two independent problems.

- Reading the discs
- Accessing the BIOS setup

**Reading the discs**

Did these discs work before in the same drive? I suppose they did but you did not make it clear. Do these discs still work in other drives. Since you probably burnt the Linux discs yourself: Have other discs (especially of the same brand) that you have burnt recently also stopped working? The drive might just be worn out/dirty so it finally has crossed the limit where it completely fails. This limit is usually reached earlier for burnt discs and especially for discs burnt with the already degraded drive. This could also explain why your previous install attempt has failed: While it was still able to read some parts of the disc it already failed on others.

**Accessing the BIOS setup**

Are you sure that you have to press some F key? The Del key is also quite common. There should be a message on the screen on which key has to be pressed. Otherwise check the mainboard manual. If the correct key still does not work, you might want to try another keyboard. If you are using a USB keyboard, also try another port. Ports on add-on cards and USB 3 enabled ports might not work in this situation.

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: While booting Ubuntu from CD(?), press any key and chose *Check CD for defects* from the menu to make sure that the disc is correctly readable by your drive. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck for more details.

Answer (score 0):

elieobeid7

Well at least you had some success in booting, but freezing monitor issue. Two possible alternative I can think of:

1. If you are trying to use Ubuntu x86_64 (64bit), installation may freeze because of nVidia graphic card issue.
2. Your success may come largely from installing Ubuntu 386 at 800x600 resolution. Once you achieve that, update the nVidia (not freeware) driver. I had similar issue with my workstation where Ubuntu failed to install, but Sabayon 9 (64bit) worked quite well. Finally I ended up with what CERN uses -- SL6.

you may also want to try burning ISO at lowest speed. I know it will help, as it did to me.

Comment: i tried burning at lowest speed using imgburn but doesn't work, so far i downloaded ubuntu 3 times and burned it on 3 dvds, as for nvidia, i don't have nvidia, i have intel r hd graphi card

Comment: i'll try sebayon

Answer (score -1):

you can try to install linux from hard drive. [Here](http://www.instantfundas.com/2007/08/install-any-linux-distro-directly-from.html) is tutorial how to do it.

If you can't set to boot off dvd or usb you don't have much options.

Comment: This might be a acceptable workaround but there are also other ways to install a Linux system without using a CD/DVD that are probably easier and safer. E.g. by using UNetbootin: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ I also wonder if you confused "can" with "can't" in your second sentence. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: (i repaired my answer to can't)
Unetbooting don't seem to be good option to install sometihink beside ubuntu, as you might won't be able to make changes 
(keywords: frugal install, persistent install.)

Comment: I dont't understand what kind of problem you expect when using UNetbootin. *Installing* (and not just booting) from media created with UNetbootin will give the same result than with installing from DVD/CD. This includes the ability to select another OS to boot from GRUB. You might want to read http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/unetbootin/wiki/howitworks to find out the precise meaning of "frugal install" in this context.

Comment: about unetbootin from wikipedia:
"Supports LiveUSB persistence (preserving files across reboots; this feature is for Ubuntu only)"

Comment: This is an additional feature for the LiveUSB system which does not exist for the normal live CD. While this in fact *allows* you to make permanent changes in the configuration of the live system, it does not prevent you from installing Ubuntu from that system, so I don't really get your point. If you don't need this feature, just don't use it.

Comment: This answer needs additional content besides 3 sentences and a link to an external website.

Answer (score -1):

- Can you **check the integrity** of DVD? It is possible that even a small
  speck of dirt can prevent the whole DVD gone useless.
- Another factor could be you burnt the ISO file at max speed. If you
  **burn the ISO at lowest possible speed** (say 2x or 4x) then the disc
  will have much less error in reading when it reads. I had similar
  issues in early generation linux (Ubuntu, Fedora and Mandrake).
- You could use Nero DriveSpeed to make sure your DVD never become unstable at high speed (or low speed).
- Are you using same DVD drive to read and write?
- What Windows version are you using? ANY Windows stability issue?

Comment: i burdened 3 dvds using imgburn and active iso burner, none works, something's wrong

Comment: For Toshiba laptop : http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletin.jsp?soid=403623
I know because with Toshiba I cannot boot from any other source such as CD, DVD, USB, or network. For my PC [6yo] the BIOS is outdated. The limited Toshiba website information is NO GOOD. 
Problem like yours are on internet: e.g. http://bit.ly/OyhtcE 
OR  bit.ly/RFIWOu

Comment: Have you tried burning ISO at lowest speed? Also, try installing Ubuntu using WUBI (I do not have experience), but people love it.

Answer (score -4):

This shows that your GRUB is corrupted. If you edit and re-install GRUB, you can recover both installed OSes.

However, if you want to recover Windows and Linux data, you can use Partition Find and Mount

You can try to remove CMOS battery and reset the JUMPERS. Allow at least 10 minutes before restarting the PC to remove all static charges if humidity is low, otehrwise electrostatic charge can damage your PC.

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/
- http://reinstallgrub.com/
- Partition Find and Mount: http://findandmount.com/

Comment: i don't have any linux data to recover, linux is not installed now, i don't want to remove battery... i'm not gonna use this option, i don't want to damage my pc

Comment: A corrupted GRUB would neither cause Windows not reading some DVDs, nor will it prevent you from accessing the BIOS setup. However it would probably prevent Windows from booting which is also not the case here.